# show buttons on search and display result for the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create the buttons named business and individual which are hidden at initial stage and once the user enter search button, the business and individual should get visible and the contents categorized for that particular button should get searched. How can I do that? Following is my HTML code:

1. My Search button will retrieve the following things(SELECT queries in PHP).
2. After retrieving, Business and Individual buttons will be visible.
3. After visibility, the person can either click Business or Individual and on clicking either of the button some data will be retrieved

   ```
   if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
   {
       $category_name=$_POST['category'];
           if(isset($_POST['sub_category'])){
               $sub_category=$_POST['sub_category'];
               $sql_c="SELECT sub_category_id FROM sub_category WHERE sub_category_name='".$sub_category."'";
                   $res_c=$mysqli->query($sql_c);
                   if(!$res_c)
                   {
                       echo "Error: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
                   }
                   $row_c=$res_c->fetch_assoc();
                   $sub_category_id=$row_c["sub_category_id"];
           }
       $city_name=$_POST['city'];
           $sql_a="SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE category_name='".$category_name."'";
           $res_a=$mysqli->query($sql_a);
           if(!$res_a)
           {
               echo "Error: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
           }
           $row_a= $res_a->fetch_assoc();
           $category_id=$row_a["category_id"];

           $sql_b="SELECT city_id FROM cities WHERE city_name='".$city_name."'";
           $res_b=$mysqli->query($sql_b);
           if(!$res_b)
           {
               echo "Error: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
           }
           $row_b=$res_b->fetch_assoc();
           $city_id=$row_b["city_id"]; 
   }?>
   ```

   Categories: ">
                  
                  
                       Sub-Categories:">
                  
                  
                       Location: ">
                  
                  
                     Business
                     Individual
                   
                   
                       
   Search

Comment: It is a post form, if you hit the submit button with "search" text it will submit the data.
1, You want to submit then show two more button?
2, Or you want a button which will show 2 button?

Comment: I see you are using jQuery. So read about `show`, `hide` or `toggle` and of course `click`. in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type="submit"` will refresh your page so I recommand you to change it `type="button"` 
**put a style to buttons and add some class:**

```
<button type="button" name="submit" class="success-btn display" style="display:none">Business</button>
<button type="button" name="submit" class="success-btn display" style="display:none">Individual</button>
```

**and onclick search show them:**

```
<button type="button" name="submit" class="success-btn" onclick="displayBtn()">
Search</button>
```

**in your script**

```
function displayBtn(){
var btns=document.grtElementByClassName('display');
btns[0].style.display = 'block'; 
btns[1].style.display = 'block'; 
}
```

**Or by Jquery:**

```
function displayBtn(){
  $('.display').show();
}
```

In this `function` you can do your searching and show/hide result like I did to buttons

Comment: Tell me for more help

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot

Comment: **HELP** with the same.. I've tried above solution but the buttons Business and Individual they just appear for few seconds and get hidden.

Comment: do you change your `type=button`?

Comment: because `type=submit` will  refresh your page and hide buttons again

Comment: It seem your problem about refersh the page check out if something does not refresh your page

Comment: but my type=submit for Search button retrieve few things. which if I change don't show any results. look for my another snippet into my answer

Comment: try this `onclick="displayBtn();return false"` in submit button